# How to extract information in systeminfo after semicolon with regex?

Tags: regex

I am running **systeminfo** command in commandline to get the system information.
I need only a few of them, not every thing. How can I exctract the information with regex?

Edit: I am using LabView, and it uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (http://www.pcre.org/).

I need only following information 
`NameOfTheHost (Hostname:)`,
`Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro (Betriebssystemname:)`, 
`07.12.2015, 07:54:09 (Systemstartzeit:)`, 
`1 and [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2501 MHz (Prozessor(en):)`, 
`username (Registrierter Benutzer:)`, 
`8.105 MB (Gesamter physischer Speicher:)`, 
`3.315 MB (Verfügbarer physischer Speicher:)`, 
`8.105 MB (Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Maximale Größe:)`, 
`2.485 MB (Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Verfügbar:)`, 
`5.620 MB (Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Zurzeit verwendet:)`

My command **systeminfo** gives following text:

```
Hostname:                                      NameOfTheHost
Betriebssystemname:                            Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
Betriebssystemversion:                         6.3.9600 Nicht zutreffend Build 9600
Betriebssystemhersteller:                      Microsoft Corporation
Betriebssystemkonfiguration:                   Mitglied der Domäne/Arbeitsgruppe
Betriebssystem-Buildtyp:                       Multiprocessor Free
Registrierter Benutzer:                        username
Registrierte Organisation:
Produkt-ID:                                    0000-0000-0000
Ursprüngliches Installationsdatum:             01.01.2010, 13:41:25
Systemstartzeit:                               07.12.2015, 07:54:09
Systemhersteller:                              Hewlett-Packard
Systemmodell:                                  HP ProBook 650 G1
Systemtyp:                                     x64-based PC
Prozessor(en):                                 1 Prozessor(en) installiert.
                                               [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2501 MHz
BIOS-Version:                                  Hewlett-Packard L77 Ver. 01.05, 29.04.2014
Windows-Verzeichnis:                           C:\Windows
System-Verzeichnis:                            C:\Windows\system32
Startgerät:                                    \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Systemgebietsschema:                           de-at;Deutsch (Österreich)
Eingabegebietsschema:                          de;Deutsch (Deutschland)
Zeitzone:                                      (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien
Gesamter physischer Speicher:                  8.105 MB
Verfügbarer physischer Speicher:               3.315 MB
Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Maximale Größe:    8.105 MB
Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Verfügbar:         2.485 MB
Virtueller Arbeitsspeicher: Zurzeit verwendet: 5.620 MB
Auslagerungsdateipfad(e):                      Nicht zutreffend
Domäne:                                        domainname.local
Anmeldeserver:                                 \\loginserver
Hotfix(es):                                    148 Hotfix(e) installiert.
                                               [01]: KB2899189_Microsoft-Windows-CameraCodec-Package
                                               [02]: KB000000
                                               [03]: KB000000
                                               ..... /* shortened */
                                               [148]: KB000000
Netzwerkkarte(n):                              3 Netzwerkadapter installiert.
                                               [01]: Bluetooth-Gerät (PAN)
                                                     Verbindungsname: Bluetooth-Netzwerkverbindung 3
                                                     Status:          Medien getrennt
                                               [02]: Intel(R) Ethernet-Verbindung I217-V
                                                     Verbindungsname: Ethernet 2
                                                     DHCP aktiviert:  Ja
                                                     DHCP-Server:     10.0.0.1
                                                     IP-Adresse(n)
                                                     [01]: 10.0.0.10
                                                     [02]: 0000::0000:0000:0000:0000
                                               [03]: Broadcom BCM943228HMB 802.11abgn 2x2 Wi-Fi Adapter
                                                     Verbindungsname: WiFi 2
                                                     DHCP aktiviert:  Ja
                                                     DHCP-Server:     10.0.0.10
                                                     IP-Adresse(n)
                                                     [01]: 10.0.0.11
                                                     [02]: 0000::0000:0000:0000:0000
Anforderungen für Hyper-V:                     Erweiterungen für den VM-Überwachungsmodus: Ja
                                               Virtualisierung in Firmware aktiviert: Nein
                                               Adressübersetzung der zweiten Ebene: Ja
                                               Datenausführungsverhinderung verfügbar: Ja
```

Answer (score 1):

You really need to give us more detail about the regex flavour you want to use or in what language. Assuming you want to use it in c# here is how you would loop over all matches:

```
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"([^:]*):\s*(.*)");
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        // matched text: matchResults.Value
        // match start: matchResults.Index
        // match length: matchResults.Length
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

You could then check, which ones you want. But to be honest, I wouldn't use regex for that task. Since you only need a few known entries of the list, loop through the lines and check if the lines begin with eg. "Hostname:" and if so take the rest of string.

Without further details we won't be able to give you a more precise answer.

Comment: I am using LabView, and it uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (http://www.pcre.org/).

Comment: In Perl the regex above would be while ($subject =~ m/([^:]*):\s*(.*)/g) {
 # matched text = $&
}